# how to find where a call is being made in my javascript using chrome developer

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have adopted an app that has a bug somewhere where an errant call is being made. I can see it here like this:

[image]

but cannnot for the life of me figure out where this is being called. In chrome developer tools, can I examine the full backtrace beyond what is given here rather than just the jquery line numbers?

Comment: You can navigate to the line in the JS file by clicking on the line number. Alternatively find the call by using search in your JS file through `Sources` tab.

Comment: thx @ShaunakD - the problem is that it's a huge concatenated JS file (a couple of thousand lines) and grep'ing the obvious things are not helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try check break on exception, and you can see the full stack trace when the exception occurs.  [image]